# SharePoint Framework: Client Webpart throwing error when testing through workbench

Tags: powershell, spfx, sharepointframework

I am following below path to deploy:

1. npm install -g yo gulp
2. npm install -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint
3. yo @microsoft/sharepoint
4. gulp trust-dev-cert
5. gulp serve

After gulp serve command I'm getting this error:
[This page can't be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/da9JK.png)

Please suggest how we can deploy SharePoint Framework?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to try to solve your own problem first. Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: What's the full exception?